# Cakephp3 Find method

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am developing this thing where we have Products. Products has Profiles and one Profile has 2 addresses. I want to get those 10 products which has the closest distance from the user. So my idea is to get the products addresses select the right one which i need calculate the distance from Latitude and Longitude and order by this field and limit it to 10. Beside this i also want to search in these products. So i need a lot of parameters too. How can i make this:

```
$connection->execute("SELECT prod.*,( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(47.678317)) * cos(radians(addr.latitude)) * cos(radians(addr.longitude) - radians(16.587663)) + sin(radians(47.678317)) * sin(radians(addr.latitude))) ) * 1.609344 AS distance FROM products AS prod INNER JOIN profiles AS prof ON prod.profile_id = prof.id INNER JOIN addresses AS addr ON addr.profile_id = prof.id AND addr.`type` = 1 ORDER BY distance")->fetchAll('assoc')
```

query by using cakephp3 find method?

Comment: You should use an expression http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions